# What's wrong with my intersect?

Tags: matlab

In this code,the first column of A is `[2,3,4,5,3]`,and the first column of B is `[4,2,3]`,so i think the intersection of them is `[4,5,3]`,but the first column of C is `[2,4]` in terms of `[2,5,3]`.

```
A = [2 2 2; 3 0 1; 4 2 3; 5 1 1;3,3,3]
B = [4 2 3; 2 2 2; 3 2 0] 
[C,ia,ib] = intersect(A,B,'rows')
```

Comment: You are comparing rows...

Comment: I don't know why this row,although I can see row in the code.But can you explain for it? I am new in matlab

Comment: Can you explain what is the result you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing rows. The first and third row in `A` and the first and second in `B` are equal, and it's what the results show.

```
A =
   2   2   2
   3   0   1
   4   2   3
   5   1   1
   3   3   3

B =
   4   2   3
   2   2   2
   3   2   0

C =
   2   2   2
   4   2   3

ia =
   1
   3

ib =
   2
   1
```

Comment: i don't know what you mean.A is a 5*3 matrix and B is 3*3 matrix,c is 2*3 matrix. so A have 5 row and B have 3 row, they are not equal.how can to compare them? Maybe i misunderstand the meaning of row and column...

Comment: @user15961 As I said above, tell us (by editing your question) your expected result for the provided example matrices

Comment: [2,3,4;2,2,2;2,3,2or3(i not sure)]

Comment: @user15961 So you want to compute the intersection between each pair of columns? It so, the result may have different lenght for each column

Comment: oh i understand,this is a whole intersect beteen each row. i think compare each elements in column at first. Thank you,you are welcomed